# How can I verify my JSON response using groovy when the response contains same key multiple times?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I Am using Jmeter to verify the response object of my restful API where I need to verify the data as well as the structure of return object. 
I Am trying to do it with JsonSlurper but it doesn't seem a good approach as it doesnt deep scan the response. What other alternative can I use to scan the complete response? Any help?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('''{
"data": {
    "MND": "2019-12-29T00:00:00Z",
    "Months": [
        {
            "SD": "01\/01\/2020",
            "T": [
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": false,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "20.00",
                    "MI": 100
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": false,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.20",
                    "MI": 101
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": true,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.00",
                    "MI": 102
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": false,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.20",
                    "MI": 103
                }
            ],
            "MR": [
                {
                    "PTG": 1.0,
                    "NA": false,
                    "S": "danger",
                    "VL": "1,536.00",
                    "MI": 100
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": true,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.00",
                    "MI": 101
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": true,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.00",
                    "MI": 102
                },
                {
                    "PTG": 0.0,
                    "NA": true,
                    "S": null,
                    "VL": "0.00",
                    "MI": 103
                }
            ],
            "MDN": "January 2020",
            "H": [
                {
                    "MN": "API Automation Testing Lower the better Metric-Sum",
                    "RT": "s",
                    "GL": "B",
                    "MI": 100,
                    "DS": "%"
                },
                {
                    "MN": "API Automation Testing Higher the better Metric-Sum",
                    "RT": "s",
                    "GL": "A",
                    "MI": 101,
                    "DS": "%"
                },
                {
                    "MN": "API Automation Testing Higher the better Metric-AVG",
                    "RT": "a",
                    "GL": "A",
                    "MI": 102,
                    "DS": "s"
                },
                {
                    "MN": "API Automation Testing Lower the better Metric-Number-AVG",
                    "RT": "a",
                    "GL": "B",
                    "MI": 103,
                    "DS": "s"
                }
            ],
            "Id": 0,
            "WR": [
                {
                    "DT": [
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 101
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 102
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 103
                        }
                    ],
                    "SD": "29\/12\/2019",
                    "WN": 1,
                    "ED": "04\/01\/2020"
                },
                {
                    "DT": [
                        {
                            "PTG": 1.0,
                            "NA": false,
                            "S": "danger",
                            "VL": "1,536.00",
                            "MI": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 101
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 102
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 103
                        }
                    ],
                    "SD": "05\/01\/2020",
                    "WN": 2,
                    "ED": "11\/01\/2020"
                },
                {
                    "DT": [
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 101
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 102
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 103
                        }
                    ],
                    "SD": "12\/01\/2020",
                    "WN": 3,
                    "ED": "18\/01\/2020"
                },
                {
                    "DT": [
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 101
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 102
                        },
                        {
                            "PTG": 0.0,
                            "NA": true,
                            "S": null,
                            "VL": "0.00",
                            "MI": 103
                        }
                    ],
                    "SD": "19\/01\/2020",
                    "WN": 4,
                    "ED": "25\/01\/2020"
                }
            ],
            "ED": "31\/01\/2020"
        }
    ],
    "MXD": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"
},
"success": true,
"error": null
```

}''');

```
def parsedJson1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response1.getResponseBodyContent())

if (parsedJson1 != actual) {
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual JSON')
}
```

IAm getting this Error:

```
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: response1 for class: Script72
```

Comment: I fail to see where do you declare this `response1`, probably there is a copy-paste issue somewhere in your code

Comment: my bad! that was a wrong paste. Actually Iam getting following error:
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script90.groovy: 13: unexpected char: '\' @ line 13, column 26.
                   "SD": "01\/01\/2020",
                            ^

1 error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following options:

1. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

   ```
   JSONObject obj1 = "expected json"
   JSONObject obj2 = "actual json"
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode expected = mapper.readTree(obj1.toString());
   JsonNode actual = mapper.readTree(obj2.toString());
   if (!expected.equals(actual)) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
   }
   ```
2. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

   ```
   JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
   JsonElement expected = parser.parse("expected json");
   JsonElement actual= parser.parse("actual json");
   if (!expected.equals(actual) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
   }
   ```
3. [JsonAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert#jsonassert)

   ```
   JSONAssert.assertEquals("expected json", "actual json", false);
   ```

More information: [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter/)

Comment: which library I need to import to use above options?